# Is it possible to run more than 1 million EC2 instances concurrently?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

According to AWS, there is a limit of 20 ec2 instances per region. However, customers can request an increased limit.

I would like to know, can one run over 1 million instances at the same time ?

Comment: Contact Amazon and be ready to offer up a large payout..?

Comment: Theoretically? Possibly. Will they let you after talking to them? Maybe, but be prepared to pay a lot of money. Would they be able to support 1 million new instances immediately after giving them a fat cheque? Probably not, will require some preparation.

Comment: This is not unlike a question such as: Can I buy 1M items off amazon, or can I upload 1M youtube videos. It's in the realm of possibilities, but not something that can be quickly done without a great amount of custom care. I'm sure they would be happy to take your fat cheque though, but maybe not if you only need them for a day.

Comment: The maximum I have tried requesting is 500 instances, which was approved in two stages, 100 + 400. After meeting the simultaneous usage of 100 instances, 400 instances were approved. For 1MM, there might be a different strategy from AWS!

Comment: _WHY_ are you asking this question? What is your use-case for requiring this many concurrent AWS Lambda functions? How long will each one run?

Comment: Could you tell what is the purpose of having 1000 EC2 instances? Are you running a machine learning workload? AWS offers services for just that. If this is for a web service, you can just use API Gateway that will scale automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of the number you have mentioned. But AWS does offer you a service wherein you can scale the number of EC2 instances as per your requirement. The Scaling Groups feature in AWS helps you to scale your instances depending on the incoming load.

When you associate a Load Balancer with your Scaling Group then as the load increases the Auto Scaling feature of Scaling Group starts creating new instances using a template made using Launch Templates in order to match the load

You can refer to the below link which will help you understand better:-

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/autoscaling-load-balancer.html